# error using quote marks

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have the code below:

```
<head>
    <title>Quote Marks</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $variable1 = "'QUOTE' \" 'MARKS'";
?>

    <button onclick="text( '<?php  echo addslashes($variable1); ?>' );">click me</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function text(texto){
            if( confirm( texto ) ) {
                alert("thanks!");
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

It don't work! I'm having problems with the quote marks... When i click the button, i want the dialog showing the text in `"$variable1"` with all quotes...

Comment: you dont need the quotes at '<php echo ...

Comment: @johnSmith — You do if you are escaping with `addslashes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the data:

- A safe JavaScript string — use `json_encode` instead of `'`, `addslashes`, and `'`.
- A safe HTML attribute value — use `htmlspecialchars`

Thus:

```
<button 
    onclick="text(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($variable1)); ?>);">
```

As a rule of thumb, dealing with PHP quotes inside JavaScript quotes inside HTML quotes is more trouble then it is worth. You can usually get rid of at least one level of nesting by keeping your JS in a `<script>` element instead of inside attribute values.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        text(<?php echo json_encode($variable1); ?>);
    }
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', myFunction);
</script>
```

Comment: hey, can i write something before the <?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($variable1)); ?>   ?